# What plug type is this?

Tags: batteries, lipo, adapter, plug

I recently bought some LiPo battery packs from Ali,

Now im trying to figure out what type of plug it has!

[image]

[image]

Anyone knows the answer? Would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like a Molex 0510050200. People tend to call tiny white 2 pin connectors that end up in hobby electronics 'JST', even though usually they're molex or molex knockoffs. Can't be 100% sure that's the right connector without trying it though. The mating connector code is 0510060200.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input of both of you. It gave me an anchor what to look for an googl.
Have a nice saturday

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially known as "JST" connectors, although other companies make them, this particular one looks like  a JST NH  or equivalent 2.5mm pitch part .

http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=182

Often used  because it is decent , common, and very cheap

Comment: Thanks for the input of both of you. It gave me an anchor what to look for an googl.
Have a nice saturday

Comment: Please accept the (most) accurate answer.